Uniformity of X Given a Doubly Stochastic Conditional Matrix
I have two discrete finite random variables $X$ and $Y$, both defined over the same finite domain. The conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is represented by a square matrix $W$, where the $x$-th row of $W$ corresponds to the conditional probabilities of $Y$ given $X=x$.
This matrix $W$ has two key properties:

It is doubly stochastic, meaning that the sum of each row and each column is equal to 1 .
Its rows are all permutations of one another (a symmetric channel).

Additionally, I know that $Y$ has a uniform distribution.
I am interested in determining the distribution of $X$. While it is clear that $X$ being uniform is one valid solution (since $Y$ is uniform), I am curious to know:

Is $X$ being uniform always the unique solution?
If not, under what conditions is $X$ being uniform the only possible solution?


Uniform distribution is the unique solution iff the matrix $W$ is invertible.
Let the row vectors $r$ and $u=(1/m, \dots, 1/m)$ represent the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Then
$$
r W = u,
$$
and if $W$ is invertible than this implies $r=u W^{-1}$ so that there can only be one solution (and as you argue, this solution is in fact $r=u$).
If $W$ is not invertible, then there exists some non-zero row vector $z$ with $z W=0$. From $uW=u$, we get $(u+\alpha z)W=u$ for any $\alpha$. Also, the fact that the row sums of $W$ are all $1$ implies that $\sum_i z_i=0$.  So if $|\alpha|$ is sufficiently small, then $(u+\alpha z)$ is still a probability distribution, and this gives alternative possible distributions for $X$.

This makes the symmetric channel condition irrelevant. Interesting

Let $A_i = \{X = i\}$ and $B_i = \{Y=i\}$. If I ensure that $\Bbb{P}(A_n \cap B_i) = \Bbb{P}(A_n \cap B_j)$ for all $n$, $i$ and $j$, then $W$ is a constant matrix (all entries $1/N$ for the relevant $N$), and $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
This barely constrains the probabilities for $X$. They can be literally anything at all, so long as each number has some positive chance to occur.
As for the correct version of your proposition, I'm not sure atm. I think you need to have some of the terms of $W$ being $0$, and some power of it being non zero. But really no idea sorry.
